# Shortcut step to get selected text without copying? How?

Tags: accessibility, shortcuts-app, text-to-speech

How can I make a services shortcut (available via right-click menu) that gets the selected text and reads it aloud? There is a "Speak Text" step, but I can't figure out how to send the selected text to it (ideally without copying the text to the clipboard).

[image]

Here's why: Outlook does not support the Mac's built-in text-to-speech functionality when composing or replying to an email. Elsewhere on the Mac, I use text-to-speech all the time when writing. Having my writing read back to me makes it easier to spot typos and recognize grammar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Apparently, you need to allow both *Text* and *Rich text* as input types and speak the *Shortcut Input.*

[image]

Comment: Where is the first command located? I cannot find the "Receive Text and Rich Text"...